# python testing data in 2d array

Tags: performance, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a 2d array with depth information, 640x480.

I want to add (row, col) values to a list where the value is in the range 800 to 2800 (true in my example data for about 5% of the values).

I have this code (python 2.7, w10, new laptop 2017)

```
depth = np.load("depth.npy")    # depth.shape = (640, 480), ndarray
obstacleList[]
for row in range(480):
  for col in range(640):
    dist = depth[col, row]
    if  dist > 800 and dist < 2800: 
      obstacleList.append((col, dist))
```

My time measure shows me that it takes almost 10 seconds to complete the list.

For further processing of the data I need only the col with the lowest dist value but I thought this would add only more processing time.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code is not a correct Python code - it lacks some punctuation. How are you sure it's processing which takes the time, not `np.load`?

Comment: Sorry, tried to correct it. Had measured time for load and it takes 0.04 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

found numpy.nanmin which finds the min value for each column in practical no time. To get rid of some values (like 0) I needed to convert my array to float (as NaN is float) and replace unwanted values with NaN

b = depth.astype(float)

b[b<800] = np.NaN

obstacles = np.nanmin(b, axis=1)

gave me an array with the lowest value <> NaN for each column in no time (0.05 secs on my machine versus the 8 seconds using normal iteration)!